# How can I make a Roslyn Analyzer project a transitive dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, sourcegenerators

I have a library that relies on a source generator to work correctly. In the `MyLibrary.csproj`, I reference the generator like so.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference 
        Include="..\MyLibrary.Generators\MyLibrary.Generators.csproj" 
        PrivateAssets="contentfiles;build"
        ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"
        OutputItemType="analyzer"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

I need this analyzer reference to be transitive, i.e. projects that reference `MyLibrary` should get the `MyLibrary.Generators` analyzer transitively.

A simple reference like so does not seem to reference the analyzer, only `MyLibrary`

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj" />
```

I want to stress that I am not looking for `MyLibrary.Generators` to be consumed as a regular assembly reference, but as a *Roslyn Analyzer* so my source generator can run as intended during compile time.

Comment: What is stopping you from adding the project reference manually? Note that if you are looking to ship the binary output from `MyLibrary.csproj`, you should do so in a nuget package, which can include the generator library.

Comment: I have an MSBuild SDK set up so presumably consumers of my library will be able to consume the generator as an analyzer reference that way, but I was hoping for a stronger guarantee via transitivity.

Comment: Have you been able to find any solution to this?

Comment: No, I haven't, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you, but I've had some luck using the Microsoft.Build.NoTargets SDK to hand craft nuget packages for project references without causing an assembly reference. I think part of the issue you're having might be related to the ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" which may be interfering with the default pack target dependency generation.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this problem? Currently having the exact same problem and I want to avoid some trickery with nuget packages.

Comment: I have not been able to find a good solution for this. Currently I'm requiring all consumers of my framework to use a custom MSBuild SDK that references the analyzer project. See [here](https://github.com/SnowflakePowered/snowflake/blob/master/src/Snowflake.Framework.Sdk/Sdk/Sdk.props)

Answer (score 2):

I have received an answer to this question on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55229#issuecomment-933233861).

It is sufficient for the library project to have the following reference to the generator project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Package the generator in the analyzer directory of the nuget package -->
    <None Remove="$(OutputPath)/$(AssemblyName).Generator.dll" />
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)/$(AssemblyName).Generator.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

(I am not sure if the Remove line does anything. It might be unnecessary.)

When the library is consumed *as a NuGet package*, the generator is automatically included as an analyzer, i.e. the analyzer reference is transitive.

However, when the library is consumed *through a project reference* (such as in the library's own unit test project), we need the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyLibrary.Generator\MyLibrary.Generator.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The examples in the original post all handle *project references*. From what I have gathered, a transitive project reference to an analyzer seems impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: Drawback: If the Generator project depends on other packages, they are not referenced in the resulting package.